# Issue with nested powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, nested

I have this code snippet where I try tro replace some strings in all files of a directory. I thought I could nest the foreach in the ForEach-Object, but this does not seem to work.

The error I get is:

> InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException

---

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $testdir\reference *.* -recurse
$replacementMap = @{"Fruit::Apple" = "NewApple";"Fruit::Banana" = "NewBanana"}

foreach ($file in $files)
    {
    If (Get-Content $($file.FullName) | Select-String -Pattern "Fruit::")
        {
        $content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) | ForEach-Object
               { 
               $line = $_
               foreach ($entry in $replacementMap.GetEnumerator())
                   {
                   $line -replace $($entry.Name),$($entry.Value)
                   }
                }
        $content = $content -join "`r`n"
        $content | Set-Content $($file.FullName)
     }
```

This code worked without the

```
foreach ($entry in $replacementMap.GetEnumerator())
    {
    $line -replace $($entry.Name),$($entry.Value)
    }
```

part. Anyone has a clue what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and a `foreach(){}` loop are two different kinds of statements. However, your issue seem to be the newline between `ForEach-Object` and `{` - move the `{` up on the same line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a curly brace closure and formatting issue on the foreach-object. You need to take care of foreach and foreach-object in a different way:

Replace your existing foreach part with this:

```
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    If(Get-Content $($file.FullName) | Select-String -Pattern "Fruit::")
    {
        $content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) | %{ 
                   $line = $_
                   foreach ($entry in $replacementMap.GetEnumerator())
                   {
                    $line -replace $($entry.Name),$($entry.Value)
                   }
        }
        $content = $content -join "`r`n"
        $content | Set-Content $($file.FullName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of processing the files line-wise, just do the replacement operation on the entire file content at once. If the content has changed, overwrite the file.

```
$replacementMap = @{
    "Fruit::Apple" = "NewApple"
    "Fruit::Banana" = "NewBanana"
}

Get-ChildItem $testdir\reference -File -Recurse | foreach {
    $content = Get-Content $_
    $dirty = $false
    foreach ($key in $replacementMap.Keys) {
        $content = $content -replace $key,$replacementMap.$key
        $dirty = $true
    }
    if ($dirty) { $content | Set-Content $_ }
}
```

Comment: How will this affect the newlines in the file? A known issue with my approach now is that it might change the line endings

Comment: It won't affect newlines at all, unless you put newlines into your search patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll use this approach from now on!

Comment: It should also be quite a bit faster than the line-wise approach.

Comment: There seems to be an issue, the replacement does not work. When I have two entries in my replacement map, the replace seems to happen only once (I added a popup in the foreach loop, and it only fires once).

When showing the value of $_.Name in the popup, the string is empty. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: @Houbie Ah, my bad. Of course we need to iterate the `Keys` from the hashtable. See changed answer.